# How to insert two columns in a CSV File using python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to insert two columns in a new csv file. Question1 data should be in first column and Question2 data should be in second column

below given code gives me this output:

```
['question1']
['a','b','c','d']
['e','f','g']
['h','i','j','k','l']
['question2']
['a','b','c','d','x','y']
['e','f','g','m','n','o','p','q']
['h','i','j','k','l','r','s',]
```

Here is my code:

```
col1=question1.split("\n")
col2=question2.split("\n")
with open("outputFile.csv" , mode="wt", encoding='UTF-8') as out_file:
     w=csv.writer(out_file)
     for row in col1:
         myColumns = row.split("\n")
         print(myColumns)
         w.writerow(myColumns)
     for row in col2:
         myColumns = row.split("\n")
         print(myColumns)
         w.writerow(myColumns)
```

the output should be like this:
question1 should be in first column of csv and question 2 should be in second column of csv file

```
['question1']   ['question2']
['a','b','c','d']  ['a','b','c','d','x','y']
['e','f','g']  ['e','f','g','m','n','o','p','q']
['h','i','j','k','l']  ['h','i','j','k','l','r','s',]
```

Please help me how can I solve the problem..

Comment: How should the output look?

Comment: i have added my desired output in post.

Comment: You'll also need to provide how your input actually looks.
Is it `question1 = [['What', 'step', 'step', 'guide', 'invest', 'share', 'market', 'india'],['What', 'story', 'Kohinoor', 'KohiNoor', 'Diamond']
...]`
Do you need the entire list on one line? Or each list element on one line?

Comment: 1st column should contain question 1 and all its data, each element of list on separate line. similarly question 2 and its data should be in 2nd column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pandas` for this.

```
import pandas as pd

question1 = [['1', '1'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['3', '4']]   #question 1 data
question2 = [['is', 'was'], ['i', 'am', 'me'],['yes', 'no']] #question 2 data

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["question1", "question2"])
df["question1"] = question1
df["question2"] = question2

df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

> output.csv

```
question1,question2
"['1', '1']","['is', 'was']"
"['1', '2', '3']","['i', 'am', 'me']"
"['3', '4']","['yes', 'no']"
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it the output you want is something like this:
    [question1 data], [question2 data]
    [question1 data], [question2 data]
    ...

In that case the following will get you there:

```
first_column = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g']]   #Populate this with your data from question 1
second_column = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4', '5']]              #Populate this with data from question 2


#Find the shortest and the longest of the lists
(shortest_list, lognest_list) =  (first_column, second_column) if len(first_column) < len(second_column) else (second_column,first_column)


#If the two colmns are guarenteed to be of the same length, then this loop is enough
for i in range(0,len(shortest_list)):
    print(str(first_column[i]) + ", " + str(second_column[i]))

#Handle that the who lists may not be of equal lengths
if len(shortest_list) != len(lognest_list):
    for i in range(len(shortest_list),  len(lognest_list)):
        print(str(lognest_list[i]) + ", ")
```